# Not rerender profile page after update username

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm starting to learn React. Profile page does not update after name change. 
The request is being processed, and I get the desired result, the username is updated, but the profile page does not reload, please tell me how to fix it. The fact is that I also have a similar problem on the page of user records, and there is a similar situation when adding a record, it also appears after reloading the page. Am I not causing a component update to succeed?

component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {users} from "../actions";


class ProfilePage extends Component {

state = {
    text: ""
};

submitName = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateName(this.props.user.id, this.state.text).then(this.resetForm);
    this.setState({text: ""});
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.user.username}</h3>
                <span>Edit name</span>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitName}>
                  <input
                    value={this.state.text}
                    placeholder="Enter note here..."
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({text: e.target.value})}
                    required />
                  <input type="submit" value="Save Name" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <p>{this.props.user.id}</p>
        </div>
    )
};
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
   user: state.auth.user,
}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
  updateName: (id, newname) => {
    return dispatch(users.updateName(id, newname));
  },
}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfilePage);
```

action:

```
export const updateName = (userId, newname) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    let headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000'};
    let {token} = getState().auth;

    if (token) {
       headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
    }

    let body = JSON.stringify({"username":newname});

    return fetch(`/api/users/${userId}/`, {headers, method: "PUT", body})
    .then(res => {
    if (res.status < 500) {
      return res.json().then(data => {
        return {status: res.status, data};
      })
    } else {
      console.log("Server Error!");
      throw res;
    }
    })
    .then(res => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_USERNAME', user: res.data, userId});
    } else if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
      dispatch({type: "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR", data: res.data});
      throw res.data;
    }
  })
 }
};
```

reducer:

```
const initialState = [];
export default function users(state=initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'FETCH_USER':
      return [...state, ...action.user];

    case 'UPDATE_USERNAME':
      return [...state, ...action.user];

    default:
     return state;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Redux you are updating the props and this will not trigger a render of the page.
Make sure you do a state change after the props are updated if you are not doing it already in the resetForm function.

```
this.props.updateName(this.props.user.id, this.state.text)
.then(()=>{this.resetForm(); this.setState({text: ""});
});
```

Alternatively you could use this.forceUpdate after the props are updated.
Another option is to use the getDerivedStateFromProps function. This is called whenever the props change. If if a state change is returned in this function, the page will render.